# How to write 2 4 8 16... in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB.Net. Please help me to solve this problem.

In a form I have added a listbox and a button. When I click the button the listbox will be filled with

2
4
8
16
32
64
128

How to do this?

I have tried this:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim number As Integer
    ListBox3.Items.Clear()
    For number = 2 To 128
        ListBox3.Items.Add(number*2)
    Next
End Sub
```

But this shows as 4 6 8 10 12 14...

Comment: What have _you_ tried?

Comment: Those numbers are *powers* of two, not simply multiples.

Comment: You can also use the [Math.Pow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function.  Oh, hey look at the example in that link!  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a loop, you can just display them one by one :)

```
ListBox3.Items.Clear()
ListBox3.Items.Add("2")
ListBox3.Items.Add("4")
ListBox3.Items.Add("8")
ListBox3.Items.Add("16")
ListBox3.Items.Add("32")
ListBox3.Items.Add("64")
ListBox3.Items.Add("128")
```

You loop 128 times and display the number * 2. Which is not what you want. You want to display power of two.

```
Dim number As Integer
ListBox3.Items.Clear()
number = 2

Do While number <= 128
    ListBox3.Items.Add(number.ToString())
    number *= 2
Loop
```

I decide to play around with for loop and generated this.

```
For number As Integer = 2 To 128
    ListBox3.Items.Add(number.ToString())
    number += number - 1
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the caret `^` to do powers of numbers, in this case powers of `2`:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    ListBox3.Items.Clear()

    For i = 1 To 7
        ListBox3.Items.Add(2 ^ i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Now let's assume you want to let the user choose the number of entries, e.g. with a "NumericUpDown" control on the form.  You can change the code to this:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    ListBox3.Items.Clear()

    For i = 1 To NumericUpDown1.Value
        ListBox3.Items.Add(2 ^ i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your number line is: Next number is a previousNumber*previousNumber;

But you are doing just a Number*2

The answer is always give the Number = PreviousNumber*PreviousNumber;

```
Dim Number as Integer;
Number = 2;
listBox.Items.Add(Number);
```

then you do a loop

If i'm not mistaken in VB:

```
For index As Integer = 1 To 5 // how much you need numbers
   Number= Number*2;
   listBox.Items.Add(Number);
Next
```

so we have:

```
Number= Number*2; //2*2 Number will become 4
Number= Number*2; //4*2 Number will become 8
Number= Number*2; //8*2 Number will become 16
```

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? I have mistaken in for syntax? or variable syntax? - i have wrote that i haven't worked with VB for a  2 or 3 years. But i gave him the correct algorithm

Comment: You are not using index variable? Where does Number come from?

Comment: Okay, sorry Number= Number*2;

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do here.